# Why does starting value affect outcome of Seeded Random?

Tags: c++, random

Trying to figure out why the starting value affects the seeded random in this code. I would expect for it to find the match at the same location for 12 character or more match no matter of the starting value for the seed, but it seems as though I am getting different results depending on the starting value of the seed which to me makes no sense. Anyone who why I am getting these results as shown from 0, 1, 2, and 3 for starting values when all 4 should flag the same values as a match to 12 more more characters.

```
Poor Key Finder 
Search for 12 or more matches
Searching through Key Values of **0** thru 1000000000

WARNING - Program Running Please Wait...

25% Complete

50% Complete

75% Complete

**Greater or Equal to = 12 ===== 923425024**

100% Complete

Completed = 1000000000


Press any key to continue . . .


Poor Key Finder  
Search for 12 or more matches
Searching through Key Values of **1** thru 1000000000

WARNING - Program Running Please Wait...

**Greater or Equal to = 12 ===== 204715678**

25% Complete

**Greater or Equal to = 12 ===== 346933630**

50% Complete

75% Complete

100% Complete

Completed = 1000000000


Press any key to continue . . .


Poor Key Finder  
Search for 12 or more matches
Searching through Key Values of **2** thru 1000000000

WARNING - Program Running Please Wait...

25% Complete

50% Complete

75% Complete

100% Complete

Completed = 1000000000


Press any key to continue . . .


Poor Key Finder  
Search for 12 or more matches
Searching through Key Values of **3** thru 1000000000

WARNING - Program Running Please Wait...

25% Complete

50% Complete

75% Complete

100% Complete

Completed = 1000000000


Press any key to continue . . .
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int delay;
long long int counter1 = 0; // Add LL beyond 9 digits
long long int endcount = 0; // while loop end counter
long long int seed1 = 0;
int match2 = 0;
int ST = 0;
int flag = 0;
float progress = 0;
int step1 = 0;
int step2 = 0;
int step3 = 0;

int main()
{
    system("color b0");
    std::cout << "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n";
    std::cout << "  Poor Key Finder Version 1.0\n";
    std::cout << "      Build 01/30/2016\n";
    std::cout << "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n\n";
    std::cout << " Enter Starting Key Value\n";
    std::cin >> counter1;
    std::cout << " Enter Ending Key Value\n";
    std::cin >> endcount;
    std::cout << " Enter Duplicate Character Counter Value\n";
    std::cin >> flag;
    system("cls");

    std::string str =
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_-+=?<>:\\/~.,;";
    std::string str2=
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_-+=?<>:\\/~.,;";
    system("@echo. Started on %date% at %time%>>LogKey.txt");
    system("color f0");
    std::cout << "Poor Key Finder - Search for " << flag
            << " or more matches \n";
    std::cout << "Searching through Key Values of " << counter1 << " thru "<<endcount<<"\n\ n";
    std::cout << "      WARNING - Program Running Please Wait...\n\n";
    while (counter1 <= endcount)
    {
        seed1 = counter1;
        srand(seed1);
        random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end()); // Shuffle the string
        ST = 0;
        match2 = 0;

        progress = ((100 * counter1) / endcount);

        if (progress == 25)
        {
            step1++;
            if (step1 == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "25% Complete\n";
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else if (progress == 50)
        {
            step2++;
            if (step2 == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "50% Complete\n";
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else if (progress == 75)
        {
            step3++;
            if (step3 == 1)
            {
                std::cout << "75% Complete\n";
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else if (endcount == counter1)
        {
            std::cout << "100% Complete\n";
        }
        else
        {
        }
        while (ST <= 85)
        {
            if (str[ST] == str2[ST])
            {
                match2++;
            }
            else
            {
            }
            ST++;
        }
        if (match2 >= flag)
        {

            std::cout << "Greater or Equal to = " << flag << " ===== " << seed1
                    << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
        }
        counter1++;
    }
    std::cout << "Completed = " << endcount << "\n\n\n";
    system("@echo. Ended on %date% at %time%>>LogKey.txt");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unclear. What is your question ? Please edit question and rephrase. And your code is (way) too long, read about an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Before you do anything else, remove `srand` from the loop.  The whole point of _seeding_ a generator is you do it only once.

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear... here is the question and problem. If I start the program at 0 and have it run to 1000000000 I will get different results than if I started it at 1 to run to 1000000000. I'm trying to figure out ?why? the same program started at 0 gives different results than starting at 1 as for the value of seed will be the same between both programs at say 923425024 but only the program that started off at 0 will flag this as a 12 character or greater match between static and randomly dynamic arrays. Also srand is in loop because injected value changes per iteration. Seed=key

Comment: Edited code in an attempt to make it readable. @DaveL , please look it over to see if I broke it.

Comment: @user4581301: Thanks for the formatting

Answer (score 2):

I now understand what you are asking!  The problem is because you shuffle `str` on each iteration without resetting it to its initial value each time, so it accumulates randomness from the previous iterations' shuffles.

In other words, you have two "seeds" -- one in the counter which you set each  iteration using `srand` and one you do NOT reset, contained in `str`'s shuffled character order.

To keep each iteration consistent, you need to reset `str` to the same base value before each shuffle.

Comment: Thank You so much! That fixed it. I moved std::string str="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_-+=?<>:\\/~.,;";   to the start of the while loop to reinitialize back to original character order for each iteration.  =)